# "They crashed in thunderous white" sentence meaning

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

These sentences are from "Dreams Do Come True" by Jim Bishop.

> The big breakers came in slowly.
>   They crashed in thunderous white.

What does the second sentence "They crashed in thunderous white"mean?
What is its structure?
My opinion is:

1. The big breakers crashed.
2. It makes the sound of thunder.
3. Their colour turn white.
   I want to know how I split the sentence "They crashed in
   thunderous white."

Comment: Your interpretations are correct. The writer uses a device called _synesthesia;_ an auditory descriptor (thunderous) describes a visual quality (white.)

Comment: How are the words composed in this sentence?

Comment: By "this sentence", are you referring to your numbered sentence 3, or the second sentence in your block quote?

Comment: The second sentence in my block quote.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "split" in *"I want to know how I split the sentence 'They crashed in thunderous white.'"* -- FWIW, it basically goes like this: They crashed. They crashed how? They crashed in thunderous white.

Comment: I want to know the meaning of "thunderous white"

Comment: @learner Did you read my comment above? The adjective "thunderous" modifies the adjective "white." The prepositional phrase _in thunderous white_ is an adverbial, and it describes the way the waves crash: the white foam and thunderous sound are combined in a single phrase. This is a literary device called [_synaesthesia,_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaesthesia_(rhetorical_device)) in which a descriptor associated with one of the senses is used to modify or describe a different sense.